# Run a Windows Docker container in mac

Tags: docker, macos, dockerfile, docker-image

i want to create a docker image locally in my mac with the dockerfile as base image as windows (.netframework) , is it possiblle to do in mac and want to run the container?

solution for building a windows docker image locally in mac and run a windows container